# Can a MYSQL database user enter in a Web Application with its credentials?

Tags: mysql, database

If I have a database "Movies" and I have 3 different users I created using the

```
Create User... identified by  ... "
```

command. Users are "A" "B" "C" with different roles, and a table inside this database called "users" where I save username and password.

Can I use these MySQL user accounts (A, B or C) in the web application "login.php"   since they are not saved in the table "users".

Comment: Are you saying that A, B and C are roles you created in MySQL, but are not represented in your application's "Users" table?

Comment: I've created the roles A,B and C, and 2 users identified with passwords. I granted the role A to the first user, and role B to second user (this only in mysql).
Now, for the web application I created a login.php file and a table called users. So when I sign up in the web application, the username and pass gets saved on the table. I know that the db users dont get saved in that table, thats why Im asking if it works if I enter those credentials in the login.php. i dont know how that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several types of user in most web applications.

The easiest to explain are "application users" - when you sign up for Facebook, or Github, or Amazon, or indeed Stack Overflow, you create an application user profile. This profile can have all sorts of attributes, and may have rights within the application - for instance, on Stack Overflow, some people have rights to edit questions. These rights apply to application domain concerns (like "question" in Stack Overflow).

The other type of user is "infrastructure user" - the credentials used to authenticate and authorize applications in the infrastructure that runs your application. These users have rights at the *infrastructure* level - in your database, those rights may include `select`, `insert`, `create table` etc.

Its almost never a good idea to have your *application* users mixed with your *infrastructure* users. You almost certainly don't want someone logging into your web application who can drop your database.

If you *really* need to do this, you have to modify your connection string, and log in as the infrastructure-level user.